# Understanding the Double Slit Experiment without Path Integrals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, path-integral, interference, superposition

Despite being presented as one of the fundamental results of Quantum Mechanics in practically every textbook, I realized this morning that I don't understand deeply how Quantum Mechanics predicts the double slit experiment.

The best explanation I have found seems to be closely related to the path integral formulation (e.g., since there are to a good approximation only two paths that a particle can take, the amplitudes due to these two paths add/interfere).

However, I am interested in how one could go about deriving the result using the methods taught in an introductory quantum mechanics course: defining a potential, solving the Schrodinger equation, using the generalized statistical interpretation, etc. Is there a simple way to see it from this angle? Or is this a result best left to understanding via the path integral?

Comment: You're right! I find this unsatisfying as well, I'm very interested in the answers.

Comment: Another discussion of the double slit ( Beltrametti and Cassinelli's book "The Logic of Quantum Mechanics") https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797948/226902

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did once look at path integrals, but they are really just a complicated way of doing wave mechanics and I never found them useful. The double slit is much easier using basic methods, and I am not sure why your books would approach it any other way. There is no potential (or constant potential if you prefer), so the solution of the Schrodinger equation is a simple wave. The wave functions from the two slits sum, so one gets exactly the same pattern as for the classical Young's slit experiment.

[image]

In the figure, where wave crests (light grey) meet crests and troughs (dark grey) meet troughs, the amplitude of the wave increases (white crests, black
troughs) creating a bright area on the screen. Where crests meet troughs, the
waves cancel out (mid-grey), leading to a dark region.

The only difference between the classical interpretation and quantum mechanics is that in quantum mechanics the wave function is simply a way of calculating the probability for where a particle will be observed on the screen, as shown when particles pass through the slits one at a time.

[image: single particle slits experiment]

Result of the Young’s slits experiment using individual electrons, as carried
out by Dr. Tonomura in 1989, showing the build-up of an interference pattern of single
electrons. Numbers of electrons are 200 (b), 6000 (c), 40000 (d), 140000 (e).

Comment: But why must the particle diffract the way it does at the slit? Surely this must be caused by a potential (say, the "slit potential") on some level, right? I've seen classical explanations for this diffraction, but they don't seem to translate easily to the quantum case.

Comment: This can be understood from Huygens principle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle, but it is simply the solution of a wave equation. Think of a point source (the slit). How else would waves flow from a point source, except radially? (the cause is the boudary condition of point source, not a potential). There is no difference in the solution of equations for quantum and classical wave mechanics. The difference is that qm gives probabilities, not actualities.

Comment: @Uyttendaele yes, as you very well point out there must be a potential that specifies the slit geometry. But the potential is infinite, so only affects the boundary conditions at the slits.

Comment: For the simulation of the double slit in terms of the Sch. equation, see the video and references linked in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/667028/226902

Comment: One possible way is Beltrametti-Cassineli's semi-classical method using conditional probabilities (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797948))